# giphy.com - Embedded grafic vs. direct link

Tags: apache, webserver, giphy

if you get a link to an image on giphy.com, you can easily use the image like

```
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/MDJ9IbxxvDUQM/giphy.gif">
```

or

```
[img]https://media.giphy.com/media/MDJ9IbxxvDUQM/giphy.gif[/img]
```

but if you open the link in the browser, you will see an HTML page:

https://media.giphy.com/media/MDJ9IbxxvDUQM/giphy.gif

How does this work? how does the link know if it was embedded or opened directly?